# Java Server stop two hour later

Tags: java, sockets

hello everybady i have simple server that receive file over tcp normally works fine but if the request is not come from client 2 hours,my server is nothing to do.if client want to request after 2 hours from server ,server nothing to do. 
Have you any advice

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketTimeoutException;
/* w  ww . jav  a 2 s . c  o m*/


public class Main extends Thread {
  private ServerSocket serverSocket;
  public final static int FILE_SIZE =128*1204;//128k 
  int bytesRead;

  public Main () throws IOException {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1072);

  }

  public void run() {

      BufferedInputStream bis=null; 

      System.out.println("Waiting for client on port " + serverSocket.getLocalPort() + "...");
      Socket client=null;

try {
        client = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("1:"+client.getKeepAlive());
        client.setKeepAlive(true);

    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

      System.out.println("Just connected to " + client.getRemoteSocketAddress());

while (true) {

   try {

        byte [] mybytearray_rec  = new byte [FILE_SIZE];
        bis = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
        String s=null;
        while(bis.available()>0)
        {
        bytesRead =bis.read(mybytearray_rec); 
        s = new String(mybytearray_rec,0,bytesRead);
        System.out.print(s);
       }

      } catch (SocketTimeoutException s) {
          System.out.println("SocketTimeoutException:"+s);
          break;
      } catch (IOException e) {
         System.out.println("IOException:"+e);
         e.printStackTrace();
        break;
      }catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println("Exception:"+e);
       e.printStackTrace();
       break;
     }


    }//While;



  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
      Thread t = new Main ();
      t.start();
     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: do you wants to end server after 2 hours ??

Comment: Where do you have your server? If you use i.e. `Openshift by Red Hat` or similar solution, this is probably normal, as I noticed they tend to turn off users machines if they stay idle for some time.

Comment: It is hard to understand your question. Can you try to translate it with Google, i.e. and post it again? Adjust the Buffersize from 1204 to 1024. Replace the while(true) with a non endless condition and remove the breaks.

Answer (score 2):

As your question is currently written, this is just a wild guess of what could happen.

The position of your `while` loop suggests the following logic for your server (pseudo-code) :

```
LISTEN for a client
ACCEPT a client
LOOP
    PROCESS A TRANSATION with client
    [ wait next message possibly 2 hours]
```

That would be wrong. There can be many component in a network that will abort an inactive connection, because it holds unused resources.

You should use :

```
LISTEN for a client
LOOP
    ACCEPT a client
    PROCESS A TRANSATION with client
    CLOSE the connection
    [ wait next message possibly 2 hours]
```

That way the connection is properly closed instead of remaining inactive and the client opens an clean connection for each new transaction.